# How prove or disprove $12^n-11^n=p^a$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $p>11$ be a prime number,

prove or disprove that

> there exists a composite number $n$ and a positive integer $a$, such that
>   $$12^n-11^n=p^a$$

I have looked up all $n\le 10$, and I couldn't find an example. So I guess maybe there is no such $n$ and $a$?  Thank you

when $n=4$, then we have $$12^4-11^4=6095=5\times 1219\neq p^a$$

when $n=6$, then
$$12^6-11^6=1214423\neq p^a$$
and so on.

Comment: how about $n=2$: $12^2-11^2=23^1$?

Comment: I know it would be proof by overkill, but perhaps Fermat's last theorem could help.

Comment: Note that $n\neq a$, so fermat wouldn't necessarily help.

Comment: @QuangHoang $n=2$ is not composite.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $gcd(m,n)=d$ then $gcd(12^m-11^m,12^n-11^n)=12^d-11^d$.

It is then enough to show that

> for any prime $q$, $12^{q^2}-11^{q^2}$ contains more prime divisor than $12^q-11^q$.

Answer (score 2):

[Zsigmondy's Theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ZsigmondyTheorem.html) says that every time you increase $n$, you get a new prime divisor of $12^n - 11^n$. So it cannot be a prime power unless $n=2$.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor+12%5E3-11%5E3

Comment: Oops a mistake. But anyway, Zsigmondy's theorem can show that there are no solutions when $n$ is composite.